# Comic book where Batman said he would save Wonder Woman if he could only rescue one person

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics

I vaguely remember reading in a comic book where Batman said something along the lines of:

> If I could rescue one person, it would be Wonder Woman.

Also, most probably it was followed by a panel showing Wonder Woman captured. The artwork seemed similar to Justice League of America (2007) comics(?).

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but that panel was followed by a panel showing wonder woman captured.

Comment: You should definitely [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/247240/edit) that into the question, along with anything else you can remember. Was it a relatively recent comic or something older. Was it in black/white or colour, how was she captured? Who was Batman talking to?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pretty sure this is *[Justice League of America Vol 2 #13](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Justice_League_of_America_Vol_2_13)*.

At the start of the issue, Batman and Wonder Woman have both been captured by the [Injustice League](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Injustice_League_Unlimited). Batman soon frees himself from the straightjacket that was placed on him, and then states the following:

> BATMAN: Even assuming that the guards are careless -- and they are -- I've got, optimistically, another sixty seconds until my escape is discovered. **Just enough time to free one of the others. And if I can only pick one, it's her.** Wonder Woman is the best melee fighter in the world.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that the context here makes it clear that what Batman is saying is that, *in the current situation* this is the optimal person for him to release.  The way OP expressed it in the question, it sounded like this was Batman expressing a global preference.  (It may well be that this is *also* his global preference, of course.).